# error deleting an object in destroyAll with Parse Cloud Code

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm trying to cascade delete all subobjects, contained in an array of pointers when deleting the parent object, but I get an error.

This is my code:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeDelete("Parent", function(request, response) {
var children = request.object.get("children");
Parse.Object.destroyAll(children, {
    success: function() {
        response.success();
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.error("Error deleting related children " + error.code + ": " + error.message);
        response.error(error);
    }
});
```

});
As I said, "Parent" has a property called "children" which is an array of pointers to "Child" objects. This is the error I get: "Error deleting related children 600: Error deleting an object in destroyAll"

Answer (score 1):

If you add this line:

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Parse.Object.destroyAll method only use when you have list objects want to delete
the method definition as follow:

```
<static> Parse.Object.destroyAll(list, options)
```

if your children is **an** object,then you can use following code:

```
Parse.Object.destroyAll([children],{
    success:function(ret):{...},
    error:function(err):{...}
});
```

[Parse.Object.destroyAll](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Object.html#.destroyAll)